# Get only values from a map (which has values as array) to an array typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to get values of a map (which has values as array) and store inside a string array in typescript.

```
myMap = {0:['a','b','c'], 1:['d','e'], 2:['f','g']};
```

Expected Result `arr['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`

Updated: I haven't used flat() function before. Without flat() function it gives below result.

```html
myMap = { 0: ["a", "b", "c"], 1: ["d", "e"], 2: ["f", "g"] };

const result = Object.values(myMap);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any attempts of solving the problem. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Get all values of object using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and then [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array.

```js
myMap = { 0: ["a", "b", "c"], 1: ["d", "e"], 2: ["f", "g"] };

const result = Object.values(myMap).flat();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

get the key and valueArray. the iterate through the valueArray.

```js
const myMap = {0:['a','b','c'], 1:['d','e'], 2:['f','g']};
var arr = [];


for (const [key, valueArr] of Object.entries(myMap)) {
  for (var i = 0; i < valueArr.length; i++) {

    arr.push(valueArr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```